# Contradiction in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 105 he state the following commentaries which I found contradictory:

[image]

Since $h_1$ is analytical, $h_1$ is continuously differentiable. Thus if $h_1(a)\neq 0$, then $1/h_1(z)$ is also continuously differentiable at $a$ because is a fraction of two continuously differentiable functions. So $1/h_1(z)$ is analytic and well-defined at $a$.

So my question is: how can we have a singularity in $1/h_1(z)$ at $z=a$?

Comment: you are proving that if $z=a$ is an isolated singularity of $f(z)$ and $(z-a)^m f(z)$ is not holomorphic whatever $m$, then $\lim_{z \to a} |f(z)|$ cannot be $+ \infty$, because otherwise $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ would be holomorphic at $z=a$ (by Riemann's theorem on removable singularties https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), thus it would have a zero of finite order $m$ there, hence $f(z)$ would have a pole of order $m$ and  $f(z) (z-a)^m$ would be holomorphic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=a$, it may be the case that $(z-a)^mf(z)$  has a singularity at $z=a$. However,  we know already that $(z-a)^mf(z)=[h_1(z)]^{-1}$ with some analytic function $h_1$, $h_1(a)\ne 0$ and $[h_1(z)]^{-1}$ is analytic in some neighborhood of $a$. Thus $(z-a)^mf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$.

Conway does NOT say that $[h_1(z)]^{-1}$ has a singularity at $z=a$. He does say that $(z-a)^mf(z)$ may have a singularity at $z=a$.